# node response.end() equivalent in spring

Tags: java, node.js, spring, http, servlets

Is there any way in spring that we can send response immediately.

I want to create a thread which will do a job. But I don't want to make the user to wait till that job completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is multiple way of doing so in Spring.

Here is their [article](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/).

If you want to make the operations asynchronously, the easiest way is to use the `@Asyn` annotation from Spring.

Here is a simple example :

```
// Interface definition for your async operation here
public interface AsyncOperator {

    @Async
    void launchAsync(String aBody);
}
```

And a simple implementation that uses the interface

```
// Need to be a bean managed by Spring to be async
@Component
class SimpleAsync implements AsyncOperator {
    @Override
    public void launchAsync(String aBody){
        // Your async operations here
    }
}
```

Then you need for Spring to configure how the async works. Using Spring boot a simple configuration class like this works:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfiguration {
}
```

Then you can call your method and it will return right away and do the treatments asynchronously :

```
@Component
public class AController {
    private final AsyncOperator async;
    public AController(AsyncOperator async){
        this.async = async;
    }

    public String aMethod(String body){
        // here it will return right after call
        this.async.launchAsync(body);

        return "Returned right away !!";
    }
}
```

The only downsides of this method is that all your classes for async operations must be managed by Spring.